# Apply multiple format rules to a single rjsf field

Tags: jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

I like the rjsf format api, it works great for me:

```
"format": "alphanumeric"
```

But I would like to assign multiple format rules to a single field, and use [transformErrors api](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/validation/#custom-error-messages) to display a different message for each, giving user more precise feedback about what's wrong. Something along the lines of:

```
"format": ["alphanumeric", "mustBeginWithLetter"]
```

but this array notation doesn't work and breaks the formatting instead :)

Is there a clean way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"allOf": [ {"format": "alphanumeric"}, {"format": "mustBeginWithLetter"} ]`

Comment: Works great, thanks! Is there maybe a way to make an alias for such format composition?