# How to access input value inside `transformErrors`

Tags: reactjs, validation, jsonschema, ajv, react-jsonschema-forms

When mapping errors inside [transformErrors](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api-reference/form-props/#transformerrors) callback, I need to know the actual value of the input in question.

I need this to create a system for composing multiple existing formats into new composite formats. I want to match the input value against each of the "basic" formats and display the error for the one that fails. The [`allOf` method of composing formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69166115/10467064) unfortunately doesn't work for me, for reasons very specific to my project.

I tried injecting the form data into my `tranformErrors` callback via currying and reading the data directly:

```js
import _ from 'lodash'
import Form from '@rjsf/core'

const makeTransformErrors = formData => errors => {
  errors.forEach(error => {
    if (error.name === 'format') {
      const value = _.get(formData, error.property)
      // ...
    }
  })
}

const WrapedForm = (formData, ...rest) => {
  const transformErrors = makeTransformErrors(formData)
  return (
    <Form 
      transformErrors={transformErrors} 
      formData={formData}
      {...rest} 
    />
  )
}
```

but this way `value` lags one keystroke behind the actual state of the form, which is what I was expecting. Unfortunately this doesn't work even when I don't pass `formData` into `makeTransformErrors` directly, but instead I pass in an object containing `formData` and directly mutate it imeditately inside Forms `onChange`, which I was expecting to work.

What are other possible ways of accessing the field's value? Maybe it could be possible to  configure (or [patch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)) ajv validator to attatch the value to validation error's params?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what kind of error validation you are trying todo, but have you tried using `validate`?

It can be passed as such :

```
 <Form .... validate={validate} />
```

where `validate` is a function that takes as arguments `formData` and `errors`.

See [documentation here](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/validation/#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: I was really hoping I could use this, but after playing around with `validate` for a bit I'm sad to say it seems to be of no use here :( `validate` does have access to the form data, but not to the actual errors detected by automatic validation. The `errors` parameter of `validate` is just an _**empty**_ `schema`-shaped tree structure that I can attach new errors to, but not access existing ones. There seems to be no way to pass data from `validate` to `transformErrors` or vice versa (either would have been enough for me). Thanks for the idea though, It was definitely worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way of achieving what I want, but it's so hacky I don't think I want to use it. I can get the up-to-date value when combining the above mentioned prop mutation trick with using a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for the message, postponing the evaluation until the message is actually read, which happens to be enough:

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import Form from '@rjsf/core'

const makeTransformErrors = formDataRef => errors => {
  return errors.map(error => {
    if (error.name !== 'format') return error
      
    return {
      ...error,
      get message() {
        const value = _.get(propPath, formDataRef.current) // WORKS! But at what cost...
      }
    }
  })
}

const WrapedForm = (formData, onChange, ...rest) => {
  const formDataRef = React.useRef(formData)

  const transformErrors = makeTransformErrors(formDataRef)

  handleChange = (params) => {
    formDataRef.current = params.formData
    onChange(params)
  }

  return (
    <Form 
      transformErrors={transformErrors} 
      onChange={handleChange}
      formData={formData}
      {...rest} 
    />
  )
}
```